# What is the equivalent of `Ecto.Changeset.assoc_constraint/3` for `has_many` and `many_to_many` relationships

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to validate that a given resource has corresponding resources in another table.

With a `belongs_to` relationship I can use the `Ecto.Changeset.assoc_constraint/3` function to achieve that goal.

When I try to use it with a `many_to_many` relationship I get the following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) assoc_constraint can only be added to belongs to associations, got: 
%Ecto.Association.ManyToMany{cardinality: :many, defaults: [], field: :sites, join_keys: 
[product_id: :id, site_id: :id], join_through: "sites_products", on_cast: nil, on_delete: 
:nothing, on_replace: :raise, ordered: false, owner: ParaBellum.Catalogue.Product, owner_key: 
:id, queryable: ParaBellum.Competition.Site, related: ParaBellum.Competition.Site, 
relationship: :child, unique: false, where: []}
```

How can I achieve something equivalent to `Ecto.Changeset.assoc_constraint/3` when dealing with a `many_to_many` or `has_many` relationship?

Edit: Here are the schemas

```
defmodule MyApp.Catalogue.Product do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias MyApp.Competition.Site

  schema "products" do
    field :name, :string

    many_to_many :sites, Site, join_through: "sites_products"

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(product, attrs) do
    product
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

```
    defmodule MyApp.Competition.Site do
      use Ecto.Schema
      import Ecto.Changeset

      alias MyApp.Catalogue.Product

      schema "sites" do
        field :name, :string

        many_to_many :products, Product, join_through: "sites_products"

        timestamps()
      end

      def changeset(site, attrs) do
        site
        |> cast(attrs, [:name])
        |> validate_required([:name])
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you post all your schema code?

Comment: I added them in the Edit

Comment: so i think instead of having join_through `sites_products` table, you can join_through a `SiteProduct` schema and define the `changeset` with validation in there. Here is the reference https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3-join-schema-example

Comment: look at this https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#foreign_key_constraint/3. This might help. I used this with `many_to_many` to check if records still associated with the record I am about to delete.